# Define object in public but create it in Constructor

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor, arduino

What I would like to do is similar to this (working):

```
class Claw {
  public:
    Claw(int pin);
  private:
    int pin;
  };

Claw::Claw(int pinNumber) {
  pin = pinNumber;
  }
```

But I want to do it with classes instead of basic types. I want to define the class in the private section (so I can use it on all the object) and execute the `AccelStepper` constructor in the `Wheel` constructor. I've tried these two solutions and they both give different errors:

```
class Wheel {
  public:
    Wheel(int pin);
  private:
    AccelStepper stepper;
  };

Wheel::Wheel(int pinNumber) {

  // This doesn't work
  AccelStepper stepper(AccelStepper::DRIVER, pinNumber, 1);

  // This also doesn't work
  stepper(AccelStepper::DRIVER, pinNumber, 1);
  }
```

How can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Note that this works, but I cannot pass the pin number then:

```
class Wheel {
  public:
    Wheel();
  private:
    AccelStepper stepper(5);
  };

Wheel::Wheel() {
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do it with a [member initialization list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

```
Wheel::Wheel(int pinNumber)
    : stepper(AccelStepper::DRIVER, pinNumber, 1)
{
}
```

Comment: Simple yet it works perfectly. I didn't even know that this could be done, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your header:

```
class Wheel
{
public:
    class Stepper; // Forward declaration of embedded class

    Wheel();
    Stepper& stepper() { return *_pStepper; }

private:

    Stepper* _pStepper;
};
```

In your implementation:

```
class Wheel::Stepper
{
public:
    void accelerate() {}
};

Wheel::Wheel()
    : _pStepper( new Stepper() )
{
    stepper().accelerate();
}
```